# Swift вызов функции

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3, swift4

У меня есть функция для проверки есть ли album в photos. У меня допустим есть "Golohram" album, но мне нужно проверить правда ли она существует на этом айфоне. Вопрос таков, как мне правильно ёё вызвать? Застрял на 2 части с completionHandler.

Функция:

```
func getAlbum(title: String, completionHandler: @escaping (PHAssetCollection?) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", title)
        let collections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

        if let album = collections.firstObject {
            completionHandler(album)
        } else {
            self?.createAlbum(withTitle: title, completionHandler: { (album) in
                completionHandler(album)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда вы вызовите эту функцию и передадите строку. Она стразу ничего не вернет, а отработает только тогда, когда сработает блок в теле вашей функции и вернет тот объект который вы положили в блок..

Сам код вызова функции должен примерно выглядеть вот так.

```
getAlbum(title: "Golohram") { [weak self] assetCollection in //assetCollection это просто имя которое я дал названию возвращаемого элемента
        guard let this = self else { return } //простая защита от потери памяти, замыкание является ссылочным типом
        guard assetCollection != nil else { return } //проверка на наличие объекта
        print(assetCollection!) //если объект сцществует, он будет распечатан
    }
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, в какой ситуации отсутствие guard let this = self else { return } может привести к потере памяти? В случае если вызывающая функция будет выгружена до запуска closure? А [unowned self] вместо [weak self] в такой ситуации не поможет?

Comment: Клоужер по умолчанию является стронг ссылкой. Если вы в него положите стронг (self) объект они оба никогда не будут удалены из памяти.

Comment: [weak self] делает self в этом closure нестрогой ссылкой, и closure не станет держать сам self, соответственно они будут удалены из памяти

Comment: Все верно, в начале коужера мы создает weak, и дальше делаем проверку существует этот weak или нет.

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ, но эта часть кода "[weak self] assetCollection" у меня вылетает с еррором

Comment: Поставьте брэйкпоинт. В каком месте? Вы в каком классе вызываете функцию?

Comment: Вызов происходит в viewDidLoad(). Ошибки таковы: "Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'", "Expected ',' separator"... синтаксис, короче.

Comment: Также мне нужно не отдельная функция, а надо просто вызвать функцию, которая у меня в вопросе

Comment: Поправил ответ. попробуйте вызвать такую функцию/

Comment: Сейчас хорошо работет, спасибо большое!